# Neural Network for Multiple Float Output

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, regression, data

I have a dataset containing 40 input columns and 12 output columns (float values).

I supposed it's a regression problem and I am wondering of how to choose the ideal architecture of the Neural Network i didn't find examples of neural Network regression with multiple output 
What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just use an output layer with 12 neurons instead of 1. Qualitatively there is no difference. For regression the output activations should be linear, and you have a few choices for cost: RMSE, MAE, or Huber Loss to name a few.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the number of outputs is equal to 12, have you tried this kind of regression problems? because I've tried and the point is that after learning almost for all inputs the outcome is similar with small changes in decimal numbers.

Comment: It definitely sounds like something is broken. But very hard to say what without seeing at least your code, and preferable your data too.

Comment: I guess you have seen professor Andrew Ng's convnets tutorial. It was annotation of face that he disscussed, Actually I meant in regression tasks when the number of outputs is large, things always don't go in right way.